# Softkeyboard hide call not working as expected in view.post(), but works fine inside runOnUIThread()

Tags: android, android-input-method, postdelayed, android-runonuithread

When I make a call(from inside of a fragment) to hide the keyboard inside runOnUiThread() , the keyboard hides, but when I do the same from inside of activity.getCurrentFocus().post(), the keyboard does not hide.

1) Below code works

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                        }
            });
```

2) but this does not

```
 activity.getCurrentFocus().post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                        }
            });
```

where `view = activity.getCurrentFocus();`

The android documentation says the following :-

a) public final void runOnUIThread(Runnable action) - Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread

b) public boolean post(Runnable action) - Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread.

Can someone kindly explain, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think when you do `activity.getCurrentFocus().post()` it is executed after the view is done laying out, re-sizing and updating. So if your view doesn't need to be updated that is not going to be executed. Did you try adding logs/break points to see if it's even executed?
If it's executed, it might be that keyboard just comes back up.

Comment: Hello @beef, thanks for the answer, the code is getting executed, the keyboard simply does not hide. There is some difference though, before hide keyboard call gets executed, the keyboard has a "done" button with some word suggestions on top of the keyboard, but after this hide keyboard call using getCurrentFocus().post() , the done button becomes an enter button and there are no word suggestions on the top of the keyboard anymore,but the keyboard does not hide. All said and done , when I use runOnUiThread the keyboard always hides.

Comment: @Ajit That's interesting. The fact that done button becomes enter button suggests that the keyboard is asked to appear but didn't receive correct information about the text field. Like what type of text field it is. Now the question is why keyboard is asked to appear again... Maybe use Traceview to see what's called